# Problems accessing LAMP installation or phpMyAdmin?

Tags: networking, permissions, lamp

I finally got networking to work, but the only page I can access is 127.0.0.1:8080. If I, for example, attempt to access `http://localhost:8080/upload/install/install.php` I get the following error:

> This webpage is not available
>   The connection to 127.0.0.1 was interrupted.

What should I do to gain access to all files in "/var/www"?

I already tried some things with apache's config files but I guess I messed them up so I `apt-get remove apache2 --purge` and `apt-get install apache2`.

I have also installed a complete LAMP server with phpMyAdmin, which I also can't access.

Comment: Did you already try http://localhost/upload/install/install.php ?? It seems that including the port number (8080) in the address won't result in what you wish.

Comment: ADDED: Im sorry, I forgot to add that the ubuntu server is on virtual machine and networking is set up trought port forwarding of vm so when i type 127.0.0.1:8080 i get to servers 10.0.2.15:80. I messed something ub thatswhy I didn't had 403 anymore, I reinstalled the whole server and again, I get 403 Forbidden. How do I get permission to access the server?

Comment: Guess this is already solved (as indicated by your comment on my answer). A 403 indeed points to a permission problem. Hint for further error codes: [List of HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message rather indicates the server being unable to reach. Are you sure you configured it to listen on port 8080? Check the following things:

1. check your `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` what ports you have configured Apache to listen on. It's shown in the line starting with "Listen", and by default points to port 80
2. run `netstat -a -t -n` to check for listening services. The column "State" should show "LISTEN" here, and the column "Local Address" has your local services. In this column, the port in use is printed after a colon, so e.g. "*:8080" would indicate there *is* something listening on port 8080
3. check your Apache error log file for details. If not configured otherwise, you should find it in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

The most likely cause is you set up Apache to listen on port 80 (which is the default), and now try to follow some tutorial which assumes otherwise. It might also involve configuring a virtual host, and you skipped this step (or didn't succeed here).

If, on the other hand, your configuration is to have Apache listen on port 8080, and it is listed by above `netstat` command properly, it could be some permission problem -- though that normally should be indicated by a different error. Just to make sure you can rule this out:

1. check what user Apache is running under. This usually is `www-data:www-data` (i.e. user and group is `www-data`). Using the command `ps -aeo "%p %U %G %x %c" |grep apache` you should see all Apache processes, having the user and group in the second and third column.
2. check directory and file permissions. Either user or group should have at least read and execute on the directories, and read on the files. Having your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` in `/var/www`, for example, and accessing an `index.html` there, the file must be at least readable to Apache's user or group, and `/var` as well as `/var/www` should have read and execute permissions given.

Comment: I had to change permissions, found a tutorial to do that - http://joomla-and-more.com/2009/10/28/how-to-set-rights-for-varwww-when-using-apache-under-ubuntu/. Thanks everyone!